# Vue CLI 3 with Sentry - How to use Vue's config.errorHandler?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, sentry

How can I use [Vue's config.errorHandler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler) in combination with [Sentry for Vue](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/vue/)?

I want to catch the errors in addition to Sentry in the app but as soon as I implement the config.errorHandler I overwrite the Sentry implementation.

**main.js:**

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser";

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "my dsn",
  integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.Vue({ Vue })]
});

// This prevents sentry from being used
Vue.config.errorHandler = (msg, vm , info) => {
  alert(info)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried throwing an error at the end of `errorHandler` after custom code? `throw msg`, in your case.

Comment: @aBiscuit Yes, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Sentry overwrites `Vue.config.errorHandler`, it saves the reference to previously declared `errorHandler` and invokes it after error has been handled by Sentry. [source](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/blob/master/packages/browser/src/integrations/pluggable/vue.ts#L98)

In such scenario, declaring custom `errorHandler` should be done before `Vue` constructor has been passed to `new Sentry.Integrations.Vue({ Vue })`.

For code example above, simply switching order of custom `errorHandler` and `Sentry.init()` should resolve the issue.

```
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/browser";    

Vue.config.errorHandler = (msg, vm , info) => {
  alert(info)
}

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "my dsn",
  integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.Vue({ Vue })]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way around (especially for who using Nuxt plugin)

```
const sentryErrorHandler = Vue.config.errorHandler
  Vue.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
    sentryErrorHandler?.(err, vm, info) // allow execution of Sentry (or any other plugins) implementation of error handling
    // your implementation here...    
  }
```